# vue 2 props undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Please help! I have 'undefined' props in child template.

Main js:

```
// some code before
window.Vue = require('vue');
import EventBus from '../components/event-bus';
// some code after

Vue.component('calendar-select', require('../components/admin/calendar_select.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            isActiveCalendar: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleCalendar() {
            this.isActiveCalendar = !this.isActiveCalendar;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        EventBus.$on('toggleCalendar', this.toggleCalendar);
    }
});
```

After this I created template like this:

```
<template>
        <div class="custom-select" v-bind:class="{ active: isActiveCalendar}" >
            <div class="box flex" v-on:click="toggleCalendar" >
                <span>Calendar</span>
                <img src="/assets/img/admin/arrow-down.png" alt="#">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import EventBus from '../event-bus';
export default 
{
// ------- start
    props: ['isActiveCalendar'],
    data: function() {
        return {
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleCalendar: function(event) {
            console.log(this.isActiveCalendar)
            EventBus.$emit('toggleCalendar');
        }
    }
// ------- end
}
</script>
```

When I do **console.log** on **this.isActiveCalendar**, the variable is undefined and in Vue plugin for Chrome is same thing.

Please, tell me, what mistake I am doing!

Thanks!

Comment: And how do you use this component that accepts this prop?

Comment: It's main thing is get value from isActiveCalendar. For  v-bind:class="{ active: isActiveCalendar}"  in this template

Comment: Show us the template in which you use `calendar_select.vue` and pass `isActiveCalendar` to it.

Comment: a common problem passing camelCase props is that html is case insensitive. you need to pass it in hyphen-case `<calendar-select v-bind:is-active-calendar="isActiveCalendar"></calendar-select>`

Comment: Justin MacArthur, tanks a lot!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case) for passing props.

`HTML attributes are case-insensitive, so when using non-string templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-case (hyphen-delimited) equivalents:`

In this example you would need to use

```
<calendar-select v-bind:is-active-calendar="isActiveCalendar"></calendar-sele‌​ct>
```

so that it would pass the value of the variable into the prop.